# How to send email via postfix using c sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, postfix-mta

How to send email via postfix using c sockets?
How to create message proggramly

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
char message[] = "MAIL From: vladyslav@vladyslav-virtual-machine\n \"vladyslav@vladyslav-virtual-machine\"\n\"Test mail\"\n\"This is a test email\"";
char buf[512];
//creating socket

int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM , 0);
//address parameters

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
//connection port
addr.sin_port = htons(8);

// Inet 127.0.0.1.
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);

sendto(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
close(sock);
```

Comment: This is not an answer therefore I will put it here; I want to suggest to use actual library to send mails intead.

Comment: yes, library is good by my task is to use sockets

Comment: Oops I didn't understood that *postfix* is library, never mind.

Comment: Try sending mail manually from the command line after connecting to the Postfix server using `telnet`.  Once you have managed to do that, make your C program send the same strings over the socket that you have previously typed yourself into the terminal.  Not saying that this is going to become a robust solution, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int i;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    //commands for server
    char* commands[] = {"eclo localhost\n", "mail from:test@example.com\n", "rcpt to:vladyslav@vladyslav-virtual-machine\n", "data\n", "Subject: Тест\n\nТест\n", "\n.\n", "quit\n"};



    //creating socket
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if(sock < 0)
    {
        perror("error with creation of socket");
        return -errno;
    }

    //parameters
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //port 25
    addr.sin_port = htons(25);

    // Inet 127.0.0.1.
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);

    //connecting to server
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) 
    {
    perror("error with creation of socket");
        return -errno;
    }

    //sending commands
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(commands) / 4; i++)
        send(sock, commands[i], strlen(commands[i]), 0);

    //closing connection
    close(sock);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: These commands are partly wrong ("eclo" instead of "ehlo", "\n" insstead of "\r\n" and others) and you did not even check the responses from the server. This will only work with tolerant servers, others might deny the sending or might even blacklist your IP as spammer. Have a look at the [SMTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) on how this should be done.